# Why is the camera view wider when using a Logi cam than what I see on screen?

Tags: camera, microsoft-teams

For MS Teams meetings I adjust the position of my monitor (with Logi camera attached on top) to have the view I want showing my background (a room, my desk is against a wall). And then just as the meeting is starting, I see the view of myself that meeting attendees can see, and it's much wider than what I had thought.

Is there a way I can restrict that view in any way? Is it a problem with the specific external camera I've chosen? That extra-wide view includes areas that I'm not intending to share with the audience.

As far as I know, this doesn't happen with Zoom. But it makes me wonder - can I trust what I am seeing as the camera view, or is that not necessarily ever accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Zoom and other online video apps, there is a way to [adjust the camera **aspect ratio** and/or zoom (angle)](https://www.fineshare.com/webcam-tips/change-webcam-resolution-and-aspect-ratio-computer.html).

If the application you use does not provide those settings, try a third-party tool such as  free Ekiwi-Blog [Webcam Settings Tool](https://ekiwi-blog.de/downloads/webcam-settings-tool-for-windows-10/) or freemium [FineCam](https://www.fineshare.com/finecam/).

Comment: Wonderful, thanks very much!